# Amazon Api upgrade seems to have removed some methods?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

Previously using AWSSDK v1.5.12.0 the following code worked just fine:

```
request.WithBucketName(_bucketName)
       .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
       .WithKey(filePath).InputStream = inputStream;

request.AddHeaders(AmazonS3Util.CreateHeaderEntry("ContentType", contentType));
```

Now I am using v2.0.8.0 and for some reason, they have completely change the api.

The part I am struggling with is the `AddHeaders` method which no longer exists (also `AmazonS3Util.CreateHeaderEntry`)

I am now unable to add the header as I previously did.

There is a readonly `Headers` property, and I can't find another way to add it...how can I do this?

Comment: I have no clue whatsoever about AWS but the API docs list a `Amazon.S3.Model.HeadersCollection` it might be what you're looking for

Comment: as i mentioned above the headers collection is read only.

Comment: The V2 upgrade was pretty extensive. Did you check the migration guide  - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-migration-guide-v2.html

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the AWS SDK 2.X removed some methods, one being the "AddHeader" method. To add a header you just modify the *header* collection directly.

**`req.Headers["expires"] = "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT";`**

Here is example of adding an expires header:

```
var client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(AWS_Key, AWS_SecretKey);

var req = PutObjectRequest req= new PutObjectRequest()
{
    BucketName = "mybucket",
    Key = "myfile.txt",
    FilePath = @"C:\myfile.txt"
};

req.Headers["expires"] = "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT";

client.PutObject(req);
```